# Python - Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, nested, iteration

I'm trying to cross check two nested list values, and if I get a match, append the values from list1 into list2.

For example;

```
list1 = [[ip, hostname], [ip, hostname], [ip, hostname]]
list2 = [[ip, ip_upper, type, hostname, location], [ip, ip_upper, type, hostname, location], [ip, ip_upper, type, hostname, location]]
```

I want to check if the value in `list1[x][0]` is in `list2`, if so, replace the value of `List2[x][3]` with `List1[x][1]`.

What I'm attempting is;

```
count = 0;
for row in list2:
    if row[0] in hosts[count][0]:
        new_hostname = hosts[count][1]
        row[4].append(new_hostname)
        count += 1
    else:
         continue
         count += 1
```

I know the above is incorrect, i'm struggling to figure out how to access the values list1 whilst traversing list2. The reason is because I need to check each row, and then the value with the row and then amend specific values within the row.

Thanks for the RAPID response!

I've tried to implement the code given but am running into trouble when trying to create a diction from my list:

wow, you guys!

```
    def doStuff(list1, list2):
        mydic = dict(list2)
        for l in list1:
            l[3] = mydic.get(l[0], l[3])
        return mydic

new_dic = doStuff(hostname, old_rows)
```

I'm receiving the error;

```
    mydic = dict(list2)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? If so, please edit your post and include your question.

Comment: can ```list2``` order change?

Comment: Just FYI, but if the elements within a `list` are qualitatively heterogeneous, it probably shouldn't be a `list`.

Comment: The order of the list is not important, just that each IP is checked and the value inserted as nesc.

Comment: My original answer expects a list of 2-element lists, yours seems swapped somehow, perhaps the arguments should be swapped too?

Comment: Besides returning the dictionary seems meaningless to me, i just created it to make things easier

Comment: I tried swapping them back around, but when I ordered it as you describe, the dictionary was empty! I appreciate your assistance all the same. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `ip` field value supports equality comparison (==), this solution may help you. It's quite plain and lame and probably not very optimised, but it works.

Note: it works for every occurrence of each element of list1 in list2, so if you had multiple matches in list2, they would all get updated.

```
list1 = [['1.2.3.4', 'ciao.com'],
         ['1.2.3.5', 'prova.net'],
         ['1.2.2.2', 'uovo.net']]
list2 = [['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'xyz.com', 'puglia'],
         ['1.2.3.7', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'zyx.com', 'lazio'],
         ['1.2.3.5', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'yxz.com', 'molise']]

print list1
print list2

for i in list1:
    ip = i[0]
    for j in list2:
        cur_ip = j[0]
        if ip == cur_ip:
            j[3] = i[1]

print list2
```

outputs:

```
[['1.2.3.4', 'ciao.com'], ['1.2.3.5', 'prova.net'], ['1.2.2.2', 'uovo.net']]
[['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'xyz.com', 'puglia'], ['1.2.3.7', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'zyx.com', 'lazio'], ['1.2.3.5', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'yxz.com', 'molise']]
[['1.2.3.4', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'ciao.com', 'puglia'], ['1.2.3.7', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'zyx.com', 'lazio'], ['1.2.3.5', '1.2.3.x', 'type', 'prova.net', 'molise']]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'm seriously overly complicating it and getting confused. thanks.

Comment: this is simple enough to understand, however it can be much slower if both lists are big enough.

Comment: Emiliano stands correct. If you do not have any multiple occurences to replace use a dictionary.

Comment: Agreed guys, thanks. I'm simple reading from two csvs and outputting to a new csv and there are only a few hundred ips to check. It will also only be done once so no need to make it fancy

Answer (score 2):

This works fine i guess, and its time complexity is only O(n + m) with n and m being the length of each list.

```
def doStuff(list1, list2):
    mydic = dict(list1)
    for l in list2:
        l[3] = mydic.get(l[0], l[3])
```

Comment: I'd avoid the double lookup in mydic and use a variable instead. Even is it's a small mydic... ;)

Comment: point taken, i hope mydic is large enough to be worth the trouble, though.. but how should i do that without having to catch exceptions? i feel like that's not a correct approach...

Comment: See top for response.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the target list on `ip` then use `itertools.groupby` to iterate over the targets.  It may have a slight advantage if there are a lot of items in `list2` that don't need to be modified (they are skipped).

```
import operator, itertools
ip = operator.itemgetter(0)
keys = dict(list1)
list2.sort(key = ip)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(list2, ip):
    if key in keys:
        for item in group:
            item[3] = keys[key]
```